# Repository pattern in SLIM 3

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

Hi I am looking to handle slim repository pattern  in the common pattern

like:

```
productRepositoryInterface 
productRepository
product
ProducCOntroller
```

How do I build that using dependency injection of SLIM

I have routing and it goes to the controller called  ProductController

then in the controller, I want to get in the constructor the ProductRepo interface

my dependencies

```
$container['productController'] = function($c , ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepo) use ($app) {

    return new ProductController($c ,$productRepo);
};

$container['productsRepository'] = function($c) use ($app) {
    return new ProductRepository( $c->db );
};
```

but I Got in the controller constructor the following error:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to ProductController::__construct() must be an instance of ProductRepositoryInterface, none given
```

Product controller:

```
function __construct($c,ProductRepositoryInterface $repo)
{
    $this->c = $c;
    // grab instance from container
    $this->repository = $repo;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you’re out-growing Slim if you’re now implementing patterns such as repositories?

Comment: @MartinBean this is not absolutely true. With Slim and packages like Slim-Bridge you can still create low-to-medium applications.

Comment: @dios231 I know it’s not “absolutely true”. That’s why I qualified my comment with _maybe_. Was just something for the OP to think about if they hadn’t of already.

Answer (score 2):

By default slim passes only the container object to the constructor. Now you have two options.

**First option**: Grab the repo from the container.

Example pseudo code:

Register the container entry:

```
use App\Service\Product\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use App\Service\Product\ProductRepository;

$container[ProductRepositoryInterface::class] = function (Container $container) {
    $db = $container->get('db');
    return new ProductRepository($db);
};
```

Create a controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Slim\Container;
use App\Service\Product\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class ProductController
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepo;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        // grab instance from container
        $this->productRepo = $container->get(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
    }

}
```

**Second option**: Clean dependency injection. Create a container entry for the controller and pass all dependencies directly.

```
use Slim\Container;
use App\Service\Product\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use App\Controller\ProductController;
use App\Service\Product\ProductRepository;

$container[ProductRepositoryInterface::class] = function (Container $container) {
    $db = $container->get('db');
    return new App\Service\Product\ProductRepository($db);
};

$container[ProductController::class] = function(Container $container)
{
    $productRepo = $container->get(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
    return new ProductController($productRepo);
};
```

The controller

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Slim\Container;
use App\Service\Product\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class ProductController
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepo;

    public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepo)
    {
        $this->productRepo = $productRepo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel O. mention Slim does not support clear [Dependence Injection (specifically the Inversion Of Control principle)](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).  So with Slim you can only  inject dependencies through the [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) pattern (which is an anti-pattern based on [Mark Seemannn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501).).

So you have two solutions:

1. Create a [Poor Man's DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). (It's the second solution @Daniel. O provide)
2. Use the [Slim-Bridge](https://github.com/PHP-DI/Slim-Bridge). This package just adapt [PHP-DI container](http://php-di.org/)
   into `Slim` so make the auto-wiring for you.

What you have to bear in mind is that `Dependency Injection` and `DI-container` are two different concepts.

- Slim uses the Service-Locator pattern (Daniel O. first solution)
- Daniel O. second solution is a Poor Man's Di
- Slim-bridge is a clear Dependency  Injection Container

Comment: It is not Slim who provide dependency injection management, it is Pimple, Slim default DI manager. Unfortunately Pimple does not support auto wiring so you either implement as @DanielO second solution (which is good although tedious when working with many classes) or use other dependency manager which support auto wiring such PHP-DI. However auto-wiring has overhead.